# Java While Loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, irc

I'm having some issues with a while loop. This while loop is run in a thread, and is the "main loop" of the thread, and I'm having issues with it not continuing if one of the if statements it loops over is false. This thread handles both sending and receiving IRC Commands/Messages for use in a minecraft client.

The code as it stands is below:

```
do {
    System.out.println("IRC Thread Looped!");
    if(tosend != "") {
        writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :"+tosend+"\r\n");
        System.out.println(tosend);
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\247f[\247bIRC\247f] \2477"+nick+": \247f"+tosend);
        tosend = "";
        writer.flush();
    }

    if((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.startsWith("PING ")) {
            writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
            writer.flush( );
        }
        else {
            // we need to pretty this ugly sh*t up!
            try {
                String parsedline;
                String args[] = line.split("!");
                String args2[] = args[1].split(":");
                args[0] = args[0].substring(1, args[0].length());
                parsedline = "\2477"+ args[0] +": \247f"+ args2[1];
                mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\247f[\247bIRC\247f] "+parsedline);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {                          
                mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\247f[\247bIRC\247f]\247f "+line);
                continue;
            }
        }  
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(90L);}catch(Exception e) { };
    }
} while(true);
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? Which statement has the problem?

Comment: You're using a `do { ... } while (true)` instead of a `while (true) { ... }` ***why?***

Comment: Isn't the loop not continuing because readLine() is a blocking operation? Maybe there is just no line available to read (in such a situation it won't return null, it will simply block)? Hope you know about it.

Comment: You catch the generic Exception `catch (Exception e)` instead of specific ones - InterruptedException comes to mind. Don't do it, or if you do it, document it well (why do you do it?). Then you **do nothing** in the catch block! WTF! At least log someting to Sys.err. At least while debugging your error!

Comment: @user unknown : That error will have nothing to do with the loop stopping as this happens whether or not it is executed, it exists only because the string parsing wont be valid for some of the motd :/

Comment: @matt disreguarding that they both had the same issue, the do {...} while(true) loop will execute all statements at least once

Comment: @ciamej based on your information, i just ran the listener in a seperate thread. thanks!

Comment: @Roman I see you've already solved the problem with a separate thread, nevertheless you might want to check my fix as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that java threads like to eat exceptions that get thrown out of the run() method.

Since you have IO such as `if((line = reader.readLine()) != null){` not in a try/catch, you might be throwing an exception and exiting.

What I like to do with threads is to put the main thread code in `runImpl()` and have the `run()` look like this.

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        runImpl();
    }
    catch( Throwable t )
    {
        // log the throwable
    }
}
```

Then at a minimum you can discover that your thread threw something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is caused by getLine() blocking behavior you could probably fix it this way. I haven't run that code so I don't guarantee it will work. Also make sure that reader is a BufferedReader.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    int n = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("IRC Thread Looped!");
        if(tosend != ""){
            writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :"+tosend+"\r\n");
            System.out.println(tosend);
            mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\247f[\247bIRC\247f] \2477"+nick+": \247f"+tosend);
            tosend = "";
            writer.flush();
        }

        while (reader.ready()) {
            int c = reader.read();
            if (c == -1) {
                if (n > 0) {
                    line = sb.toString();
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                }
                break;
            }
            if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
                line = sb.toString();
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                break;
            }
            sb.append((char)c);
            n++;
        }

        if(line != null){
            if (line.startsWith("PING ")) {
                writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
                writer.flush( );
            }
            else
            {
                //we need to pretty this ugly shit up!
                try{
                    String parsedline;
                    String args[] = line.split("!");
                    String args2[] = args[1].split(":");
                    args[0] = args[0].substring(1, args[0].length());
                    parsedline = "\2477"+args[0] +": \247f"+ args2[1];
                    mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\247f[\247bIRC\247f] "+parsedline);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\247f[\247bIRC\247f]\247f "+line);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            line = null;
            n = 0;
        }

        try{Thread.sleep(90L);}catch(Exception e){};
    } while(true);
```